# .Net core + AutoMapper + Lazy loading = Error mapping types

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, lazy-loading

When I run my application it throws an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Albums' on
>   detached entity of type 'ArtistProxy'. Lazy-loading is not supported
>   for detached entities or entities that are loaded with
>   'AsNoTracking()'.
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: Artist -> Artist Data.Entities.Artist ->
>   Services.Models.Artist
>
> Type Map configuration: Artist -> Artist Data.Entities.Artist ->
>   Services.Models.Artist
>
> Destination Member: Albums

Albums is the property that I'm trying to load lazily.
The exception tells me that I can't use AsNoTracking, which I don't, and my entity should not be detached neither.

This is my configuration for the DbContext

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => 
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                       .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext"))
            );
```

I also tryed using LifeStyle Transient, but same result.

Entity:

```
public class Artist : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```

DAL:

```
public Artist Get(int id)
        {
            return _context.Artists.Find(id);
        }
```

Services:

```
public Artist Get(int id)
        {
            return _mapper.Map<Artist>(_artistDal.Get(id));
        }
```

My mapping profile is just:

```
CreateMap< Data.Entities.Artist, Artist>();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Where is your MappingProfile? You can use .Include("ChildEntity")

Comment: seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107513/getting-attempt-was-made-to-lazy-load-navigation-property-on-detached-entity-d

Comment: check [This](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13173)

Comment: @kudlatiger, thank you! I don't want to use Include as that would eagerly load the data, I know it doesn't make a difference in my example but for exercise purposes I would like to load it lazily

Comment: In the examples you provided they are using AsNoTracking and that would disable lazy loading, but I'm not