# Cannot access navigation properties when projecting within a constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to cast my database entity from a DbSet into a context model. My database currently uses lazy loading to load the navigation properties. I am able to achieve this just by doing `.Where(d => new ContextClass { Prop1 = d.Prop1, Prop2 = d.Prop2.Prop })`. But say now that `ContextClass` has a constructor that takes in `d` and I do the property initializing in there, I'm no longer able to access the navigation properties and get a lazy loading issue.

My objects:

```
public class Entity1
{
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }
  public virtual Entity2 Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
  public string Prop { get; set; }
}

public class ContextClass
{
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }
  public string Prop2 { get; set; }

  public ContextClass()
  {
  }

  public ContextClass(Entity1 entity)
  {
    Prop1 = entity.Prop1;
    Prop2 = entity.Prop2.Prop;
  }
}
```

Working query:

```
  .Select(e => new ContextClass
  {
    Prop1 = e.Prop1,
    Prop2 = e.Prop2.Prop
  })
  .ToListAsync();
```

Non-working query:

```
  .Select(e => new ContextClass(e))
  .ToListAsync();
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning: An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Entity2' on detached entity of type 'Entity1Proxy'. Lazy-loading is not supported for detached entities or entities that are loaded with 'AsNoTracking()'.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107513/getting-attempt-was-made-to-lazy-load-navigation-property-on-detached-entity-d

Comment: Simply don't use such constructors. As you already saw, they are not working, I mean, cannot be translated to SQL and are evaluated locally. Use property projection as in the working example.

Comment: @Renat not exactly what I'm looking for since I already have those plumbing setup.

Comment: @IvanStoev I suppose you're right from a design perspective. It's doing LINQ to SQL and such constructor can't be translated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using an extension method to do the usual LINQ to SQL select statement instead of the constructor initialization.

```
public static IQueryable<ContextClass> SelectAsContext(this IQueryable<Entity1> queryable)
{
  return queryable.Select(x => new ContextClass
  {
    Prop1 = x.Prop1,
    Prop2 = x.Prop2.Prop
  });
}
```

So in the calling code:

```
var contexts = await queryable.SelectAsContext().ToListAsync();
```

The idea of the constructor was so I didn't have to cast it every single time I want the context. Using this extension method also serves the same purpose since the logic is still encapsulated.