# Join returns duplicate values

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I was porting an existing .NET code to .NET core.

There is a specific join code that is not working in EFCore. The code is :

```
var values = (from config in tblConfig
                               join info in tblInfo on config.No equals info.No
                               where (
                                     //some conditions
                                     )
                               select config).ToList();
```

In EFCore this returns a collection where most of the data are duplicated. Especially, there is a column `regNo`  which in some cases are "-1". This value is duplicated in all the rows after the join.

I tried the grouping, removing the conditions etc as mentioned in some other post. But didn't work. I am pointing this column since it is easy to understand.

Config Table
[image]

Info Table
[image]

Based on the `No` field I need to join. It seems all the empty cells replaced with non-empty content from same table.

Comment: Can you show **tblConfig** and **tblInfo** with some of their data, so that we could understand it better. Also without expanding the result list, it would be hard to see what is being duplicated exactly.

Comment: I am sorry! This is just a field I filtered where clearly the duplication can bee seen. Expanding the whole data could harm private data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I was getting duplicate values ( First row is repeated for all the other rows).

This occurs when we retrieve values from a table having no unique keys. The number of rows returned will be correct but they will be duplicates of the first row. To solve, use [AsNoTracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-5.0.0) . I got the clue from [forums.asp.net](https://forums.asp.net/t/1864180.aspx?EF%20returning%20two%20identical%20records%20when%202%20different%20records%20are%20in%20the%20table%20)

When this is used chances are there that it will miss the Navigation properties. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107513/getting-attempt-was-made-to-lazy-load-navigation-property-on-detached-entity-d) answer to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning all instances of `config` so every time it occurs via the `tblInfo` join you will see it.

Quick fix - You could make your query distinct like so:

```
var values = (from config in tblConfig
    join info in tblInfo on config.No equals info.No
    where (
        //some conditions
    )
    select config).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @scgough. Still the no change. The regNo field where values are -1 are getting filled with non-zero values.